# Vue named views with lazy loading

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to create my routes, but I want them to all use the default `router-view` in my **app**.
Looking at the documentation:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html

I should be able to target views by doing something like this:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: {
      default: Home
    },
  },
]
```

I want to do this with a child, so I did this:

```
{
  path: "/categories",
  name: "categories",
  meta: {
    title: "Categories",
  },
  component: Categories,
  children: [
    {
      path: ":slug",
      name: "product-list",
      meta: {
        title: "Categories",
      },
      component: { default: ProductList },
      ],
    },
  ],
},
```

I get no compile errors, but when navigating to `/categories/televisions` it only shows the **Categories** component, not the **ProductList**.

So my first question is, can children target app level `router-view`?
I also tried to add a new `router-view` like this:

```
<router-view />
<router-view name="root" />
```

and then updated my routes to this:

```
{
  path: "/categories",
  name: "categories",
  meta: {
    title: "Categories",
  },
  component: Categories,
  children: [
    {
      path: ":slug",
      name: "product-list",
      meta: {
        title: "Categories",
      },
      component: { root: ProductList },
    },
  ],
},
```

But this didn't work either.
If it is possible to do this, then my next question, which is where I am heading.
Can I use lazy loaded components and target named/default `router-view`s?
For example, I have this function:

```
const lazyLoad = (name) => {
  return () => import(`../views/${name}/${name}.component.vue`);
};
```

Which I call from my routes like this:

```
{
  path: "/categories",
  name: "categories",
  meta: {
    title: "Categories",
  },
  component: lazyLoad("categories"),
  children: [
    {
      path: ":slug",
      name: "product-list",
      meta: {
        title: "Categories",
      },
      component: lazyLoad("product-list"),
    },
  ],
},
```

Can I do it like this?

```
{
  path: "/categories",
  name: "categories",
  meta: {
    title: "Categories",
  },
  component: lazyLoad("categories"),
  children: [
    {
      path: ":slug",
      name: "product-list",
      meta: {
        title: "Categories",
      },
      component: { default: lazyLoad("product-list") },
    },
  ],
},
```

and target the root `router-view`?

Comment: *can children target app level router-view?* No. As soon as you have `children` array in route definition, the component assigned to render that route must contain its own `<router-view>`